# Bind mounts not visible in chroot

Tags: mount, chroot

I am using a debootstrap envs on my Arch system.
I bind-mount some directories from my home dir into the chroot fs home dir, ie. `/home/user/foo` → `/stretch/home/user/foo`. I can see the content from the host Arch system in both places, but from within the chroot environment when logged in as `user`, the `foo` dir is just empty.

Edit: I should not that the same setup used to work, but for some reason now doesn't. I'm not aware of any relevant configuration having changed.

How is this possible?

Comment: Looks like there might be some interference from the `arch-chroot` script which I'm using. Sheesh.